# customize color of bar chart based on value in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly go figure instead of plotly express. so I use go.Bar(), How to color the bar based on the value?

I am thinking to loop over one value at a time to plot one bar for one value such that different bar will have different colors. Now the question is how to customize the color based on value, for example, from small value to larger value use colors from blue to red.

Here is what I did for subplot case:

```
    for ix_loc,loc in enumerate(time_plot_location_list):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(
            x=[time_plot_location_list[ix_loc]],   # single data have to use list [data]
            y=[slope_list[ix_loc]],  
            text=slope_list[ix_loc],
            hoverinfo='text',
            ),
            row=row,
            col=1,
                     )
```

[image]
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, while looking at [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/bar-charts/) we can see examples that are easily achievable with Plotly express but "undocumented" on `plotly.graph_objects`. In these occasions we can execute the example with plotly express, and explore what's going on with `fig.data[0]` (for example). Then, we can replicate the options on regular `plotly.graph_objects`.

Here is how you achieve it:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(20)
y = np.random.rand(len(x)) * 10
fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(
        x=x, y=y,
        marker=dict(
            color=np.cos(x / 3),
            colorscale="Bluered_r",
            showscale=True,
            colorbar=dict(title="value"),
        ),
    )
])
```

[image]

Comment: wow, David, I kept goolgling it for a long time and never found a good solution. You nailed it. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate. Can I ask you one more question? for your code, if I want to change text format, how to do it? I am doing like text=f'{y:.2f}', and it didn't work since y is a list instead of a single number. How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks David, I got it now, using texttemplate='%{y:.2f}'

Comment: Hi David, if I want to customize colorscale, how to do it? For example,         colorscale= [
          [0, 'rgb(0,0,139)'],
          [0.25, 'rgb(0,0,255)'],
          [0.45, 'rgb(0,255,255)'],
          [0.65, 'rgb(0,128,0)'],
          [0.85, 'rgb(255,255,0)'],
          [1, 'rgb(255,0,0)']
        ],   then I define marker=dict(color=colobar_colorvalues,colorscale=colorscale_goodJet,showscale=True), it give me an error saying colorscale can only be a string like 'Bluered' orr "jet' etc. Can I use my own color scale? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Plotly are you using? `import plotly;print(plotly.__version__)` . I've tried your code and it works fine with Plotly 5.10.0.

Comment: Yes David I ran it again and it works now. Thanks